# How can i refactor this block of code for appending data to object

Tags: jquery, append

I have created a FormData object and appending elements to it using the following lines of codes. It works fine for me, but i want to know if there is a refactored way to do this.

```
var form_data = new FormData();

//Append the data into the FormData object 
form_data.append('action', 'my_action');
form_data.append('username', $("[name=username]").val());
form_data.append('email', $("[name=email]").val());
form_data.append('first_name', $("[name=first_name]").val());
form_data.append('last_name', $("[name=last_name]").val());
form_data.append('website', $("[name=website]").val());
form_data.append('password', $("[name=password]").val());
```

I am sending this form_data in ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    url: register_data.admin_url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false, 
    success: function( response ) {
        alert( 'Got this from the server: ' + response );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to send the values of all form inputs within the `form` tag in the request, then you can simplify the code by providing the reference of the `form` to the `FormData` constructor. Try this:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: register_data.admin_url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: new FormData(this), // < populates the FormData with all values in the form
        processData: false,
        contentType: false, 
        success: function(response) {
            alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: i have not used the form tag in my form.

Comment: You really should be, for UX and accessibility reasons

Comment: ok, i will. but is there a way to shorten the code if i do not use form tag?

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass the form to the constructor of `FormData` to [retrieve data from HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#Retrieving_a_FormData_object_from_an_HTML_form)

**HTML**

```
<form name="foo">
    ...
</form>
```

**JS**

```
var form = document.forms.namedItem("foo");
form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {
      var form_data = new FormData(form);
}
```

Comment: i have not used the form tag in my html.